# Sull'uso di "ma è invece"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, conjunctions

Sin dall'infanzia a scuola viene insegnato che la congiunzione "ma" non va mai accompagnata ad altre avversative, al punto che "ma però", "ma invece" e simili vengono sempre segnati come errori blu.
E non c'è dubbio che espressioni come "Volevo un gelato ma però non avevo i soldi per comprarlo" o "Avevo voglia di uscire ma invece sono rimasto a casa per finire un libro" suonino scorrette, anche se pare che in passato siano state usate (soprattutto il "ma però") anche dagli autori più illustri, Manzoni incluso.

Ci sono tuttavia dei casi in cui l'orecchio stesso sembra reclamare l'accostamento del "ma" e dell'"invece", per esempio in una frase come: "Tizio è inadeguato a parlare di letteratura ma, fresco di studi, è invece così appassionato di astronomia che sarebbe più indicato per una lezione sul sistema solare".

In questo caso, il periodo si reggerebbe anche senza l'"invece" ma, senza l'avverbio, sembra perdere qualcosa, forse più sul campo emotivo: nello specifico, viene meno il risalto che si vorrebbe dare al fatto che Tizio è prima di tutto appassionato di astronomia.

Personalmente in casi del genere mi sentirei di accettare l'uso di espressioni come "ma è invece" o analoghe ma mi chiedo se ci siano validi argomenti che lo sconsiglino.

Comment: "Ma è invece" - al mio orecchio personale - suona male. Forse preferirei qualcosa come "ma è al contrario...". Nella frase indicata "Tizio è inadeguato a parlare di letteratura ma, fresco di studi, è invece così appassionato di astronomia che sarebbe più indicato per una lezione sul sistema solare" mi "suona" meglio forse perché c'è qualcosa frapposto tra "ma" ed "è invece".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Dovresti ignorare chiunque dica che “ma però” è un errore. Lo scriveva persino Dante: “ma però di levarsi era neente” (_Inferno_, Canto XXII, Verso 143), “ma però che già mai di questo fondo non tornò vivo alcun” (_Inferno_, Canto XXVII, Versi 64-65).

Comment: L'espressione "ma è invece" non mi sembra estrana: credo di averla incontrata parecchie  volte. Vedo che si trova su [molti libri](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ma+%C3%A8+invece%22&sxsrf=ALeKk01VmSaSlTBr3VvH2spwSSTij2BogA:1589457286319&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd2b7npbPpAhWB4YUKHd7iDFEQ_AUICygG). Non sono italiana, ma ho letto molto in italiano: mi riferisco alla mia esperienza personale come lettrice. Si trova anche, per esempio, in un [articolo di Tullio De Mauro nell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/semantica_%28Enciclopedia-del-Novecento%29/).

Comment: Non c'è niente di “scorretto” in quegli accostamenti di parole; al massimo è una questione di registri linguistici. A seconda di come ci si esprime il risultato può suonare più formale o più colloquiale, più asettico o più espressivo: è a questo che è bene far caso. In ogni caso, la frase sull'appassionato di astronomia mi suona normalissima.

Comment: Grazie per il benvenuto e per tutti gli altri interventi: ne ricavo la conferma che l'uso - in effetti piuttosto informale - di questa espressione non è poi così scorretta come può sembrare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, Vittorio Coletti spiega che la congiunzione *ma* può avere due valori diversi e che, per questa ragione, è frequente il suo uso in unione ad altre congiunzioni con valore di contrapposizione:

> Le congiunzioni coordinative possono avere valori diversi:
>   unire due o più elementi (le copulative *e*, *né*, *anche*, *neanche* ecc.), opporli, nel senso che l'uno esclude l'altro (le disgiuntive *o*, *oppure*), contrapporli, nel senso che l'uno si differenzia dall'altro ma non lo esclude (le avversative *ma*, *però*), o sostituire l'uno con l'altro, nel senso che la negazione dell'uno comporta l'affermazione dell'altro (le sostitutive *ma*, *bensì*). 
>   
>         Come si vede *ma* ha doppio valore. C'è il *ma* che, con valore oppositivo, introduce la sostituzione dell'antecedente, nel significato di *bensì*: «Angelo non è stanco ma pigro», o di *invece*, «sembrava notte ma erano appena le cinque»; e c'è il *ma* che, con valore limitativo, corregge e integra l'antecedente nel significato di *però*, *tuttavia*: «poco ma sicuro». Di qui il frequente suo uso in unione 
>   con una di queste congiunzioni appena menzionate.

In una frase come quella della domanda

> Tizio è inadeguato a parlare di letteratura ma, fresco di studi, è invece così appassionato di astronomia che sarebbe più indicato per una lezione sul sistema solare

accade che *ma* ha il valore limitativo di *però*, *tuttavia* e non quello oppositivo-sostitutivo di *invece*. Per questa ragione non c'è nessun problema in accostare questo *ma* a *invece*, perché queste due congiunzioni hanno ruoli diversi nella frase (contrasto e sostituzione).

Riguardo all'uso di *ma però* che si è anche menzionato nella domanda, Coletti espone:

> È ricorrente l'impressione che sia un errore usare insieme la coppia di congiunzioni avversative *ma però*. Non è sbagliato, come attestano autorevoli usi antichi, da Dante a Manzoni; tuttavia dà fastidio negli usi formali della lingua e persino il correttore automatico di Word lo sconsiglia. Ma c'è una ragione in questo accoppiamento, ben spiegata da Sabatini, e sta nel ruolo di rinforzo e disambiguazione del *ma* svolto dal *però* che segue (significa: questo *ma* non è sostituibile da *bensì* ma, appunto, da *però*, è cioè un *ma* limitativo non oppositivo).